# How to solve undefined index error

Tags: php, undefined-index

```
if(isset($_SESSION['evt_year']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_title']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_sdate']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_place']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_stime']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_etime']) 
   || isset($_SESSION['evt_desc'])) {
    $output.=$_GET['title']; //the error is here
}
else {
    $output.="";
}
```

Notice the error I got:

> Undefined index: title in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ICT\abc\cal1\EventCalender\classes\EventRecordForm.php
>   on line 13

Comment: $_GET['title'] hasn't been set. Is the `<input>` withe the name 'title' defined on your form, or is the variable set in your querystring?

Comment: the variable set is in the query string. but still got the same undefined error... should i change into some thing else? like REQUEST or POST.

Comment: @Alin just FYI, this is a notice. Which you can avoid printing in page by putting this `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` code on top of your php files. This will print out all other errors except notices.

That being said; best practices for this kind of error is to define variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing a lot of variables, but none of them are the variable that is read from.

should be e.g.:

```
if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
     $output.=$_GET['title']; // there is no error here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check `isset()` on the `$_GET` variable before appending it:

`if ( isset( $_GET['title'] ) ) $output.=$_GET['title'];`

The error occurs because $_GET['title'] has not been populated.

Answer (score 1):

Before you check/use a variable, it needs to be defined or checked it it really exists. This has been introduced in PHP 5.3.0.

**WRONG:**

```
$output = $_GET['title'];
```

**CORRECT:**

```
if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
    $output = $_GET['title'];
}
```